# Copy non xml resources

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I need to process xml file and copy some resources that occur in it

Input resources

```
-inputFolder
  -1.xml
  -1.jpg
  -2.jpg
```

Content of 1.xml:

```
<links>
   <link ref="1.jpg"/>
   <link ref="2.jpg"/>
</links>
```

Output resources

```
-outputFolder
  -1.xml.out
  -1.jpg
  -2.jpg
```

Content of 1.xml.out:

```
<links_new>
  <link_new ref_new="1.jpg"/>
  <link_new ref_new="2.jpg"/>
</links_new>
```

Thus I want to copy 1.jpg and 2.jpg, Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean with "copy"? Do you want to transform the XML and copy the nodes or do you want to copy the files named by the nodes? The first could be a job for XSLT, the latter ain't.

Comment: What do you mean with "copy"? What the wanted output is?

Comment: @musiKk I want to copy the files

Comment: You can easily create **1.xml.out** with XSLT, but you can't copy the files in the output folder via XSLT. You can use ANT or a shell script to perform both tasks in one.

Comment: @Nawa: You can't do this with XSLT. XSLT is for transforming XML into other documents. It can't execute commands. You should look for a programming environment you can use on your target machine (Perl, Python, whatever), parse the XML and act accordingly.

Comment: As a follow-up to @empo's comment, you can use XSLT to dynamically generate a custom ANT or shell script from the input XML with specific file copy commands, execute the XSLT to generate the output, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [XML starlet command tool](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) to parse xml files.

To copy 1.jpg and 2.jpg use the following command (works on unix or cygwin):

```
xml sel -t -m "/links/link/@ref" -v '.' -o ';' 1.xml | xargs -d';' -I {} cp /input/path/{} /output/path/
```

The command

```
xml sel -t -m "/links/link/@ref" -v '.' -o ';' 1.xml
```

selects all jpg files and separates them by ';'.

Then `xargs` parses the input and pass it to `cp` which copies files to the destination directory.

Comment: It isn't suitable, only xslt script must be used